# How to send data to AudioServiceTask class which extends BackgroundAudioTask from UI

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

Well, I'm stuck on this problem. I have a code for `audioservice` (`audioplayer.dart`) which takes a `queue` to play. I'm getting the queue from `playlist.dart` in `audioplayer.dart` using `ModalRoute` and save in a global variable `queue`. Then, I initialize the AudioPlayerService. Now everything till here is fine but inside the `AudioPlayerTask` class which extends `BackgroundAudioTask`, when I try to access the variable (inside `onStart`) it comes out to be an empty list. I don't know where the problem is and I'm not very much familier with the `BackgroundAudioTask` class. Here's how it looks like:

```
import .....

List<MediaItem> queue = [];

class TempScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TempScreenState createState() => _TempScreenState();
}

class _TempScreenState extends State<TempScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        queue = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
        // NOW HERE THE QUEUE IS FINE
        return Container(.....all ui code);
        }

    // I'm using this button to start the service
    audioPlayerButton() {
    AudioService.start(
      backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint,
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio Service Demo',
      androidNotificationColor: 0xFF2196f3,
      androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
      androidEnableQueue: true,
    );
    AudioService.updateQueue(queue);
    print('updated queue at the start');
    print('queue now is $queue');
    AudioService.setRepeatMode(AudioServiceRepeatMode.none);
    AudioService.setShuffleMode(AudioServiceShuffleMode.none);
    AudioService.play();
  }
      }
    

void _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint() async {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();
  Seeker _seeker;
  StreamSubscription<PlaybackEvent> _eventSubscription;
  String kUrl = '';
  String key = "38346591";
  String decrypt = "";
  String preferredQuality = '320';

  int get index => _player.currentIndex == null ? 0 : _player.currentIndex;
  MediaItem get mediaItem => index == null ? queue[0] : queue[index];

  // This is just a function i'm using to get song URLs
  fetchSongUrl(songId) async {
    print('starting fetching url');
    String songUrl =
        "https://www.jiosaavn.com/api.php?app_version=5.18.3&api_version=4&readable_version=5.18.3&v=79&_format=json&__call=song.getDetails&pids=" +
            songId;
    var res = await get(songUrl, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resEdited = (res.body).split("-->");
    var getMain = jsonDecode(resEdited[1]);
    kUrl = await DesPlugin.decrypt(
        key, getMain[songId]["more_info"]["encrypted_media_url"]);
    kUrl = kUrl.replaceAll('96', '$preferredQuality');
    print('fetched url');
    return kUrl;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    print('inside onStart of audioPlayertask');
    print('queue now is $queue');
    // NOW HERE QUEUE COMES OUT TO BE AN EMPTY LIST
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration.speech());

    if (queue.length == 0) {
      print('queue is found to be null.........');
    }
    _player.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      if (index != null) AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(queue[index]);
    });
    // Propagate all events from the audio player to AudioService clients.
    _eventSubscription = _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      _broadcastState();
    });
    // Special processing for state transitions.
    _player.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
      switch (state) {
        case ProcessingState.completed:
          AudioService.currentMediaItem != queue.last
              ? AudioService.skipToNext()
              : AudioService.stop();
          break;
        case ProcessingState.ready:
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });

    // Load and broadcast the queue
    print('queue is');
    print(queue);
    print('Index is $index');
    print('MediaItem is');
    print(queue[index]);
    try {
      if (queue[index].extras == null) {
        queue[index] = queue[index].copyWith(extras: {
          'URL': await fetchSongUrl(queue[index].id),
        });
      }

      await AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue);
      await _player.setUrl(queue[index].extras['URL']);
      onPlay();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      onStop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onSkipToQueueItem(String mediaId) async {
    // Then default implementations of onSkipToNext and onSkipToPrevious will
    // delegate to this method.
    final newIndex = queue.indexWhere((item) => item.id == mediaId);
    if (newIndex == -1) return;
    _player.pause();
    if (queue[newIndex].extras == null) {
      queue[newIndex] = queue[newIndex].copyWith(extras: {
        'URL': await fetchSongUrl(queue[newIndex].id),
      });
      await AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue);
      // AudioService.updateQueue(queue);
    }
    await _player.setUrl(queue[newIndex].extras['URL']);
    _player.play();
    await AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(queue[newIndex]);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onUpdateQueue(List<MediaItem> queue) {
    AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue = queue);
    return super.onUpdateQueue(queue);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onPlay() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> onPause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekTo(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> onFastForward() => _seekRelative(fastForwardInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onRewind() => _seekRelative(-rewindInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekForward(bool begin) async => _seekContinuously(begin, 1);

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekBackward(bool begin) async => _seekContinuously(begin, -1);

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    await _player.dispose();
    _eventSubscription.cancel();

    await _broadcastState();
    // Shut down this task
    await super.onStop();
  }

  Future<void> _seekRelative(Duration offset) async {
    var newPosition = _player.position + offset;
    // Make sure we don't jump out of bounds.
    if (newPosition < Duration.zero) newPosition = Duration.zero;
    if (newPosition > mediaItem.duration) newPosition = mediaItem.duration;
    // Perform the jump via a seek.
    await _player.seek(newPosition);
  }

  void _seekContinuously(bool begin, int direction) {
    _seeker?.stop();
    if (begin) {
      _seeker = Seeker(_player, Duration(seconds: 10 * direction),
          Duration(seconds: 1), mediaItem)
        ..start();
    }
  }

  /// Broadcasts the current state to all clients.
  Future<void> _broadcastState() async {
    await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.skipToNext,
      ],
      systemActions: [
        MediaAction.seekTo,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      ],
      androidCompactActions: [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: _getProcessingState(),
      playing: _player.playing,
      position: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
    );
  }

  AudioProcessingState _getProcessingState() {
    switch (_player.processingState) {
      case ProcessingState.idle:
        return AudioProcessingState.stopped;
      case ProcessingState.loading:
        return AudioProcessingState.connecting;
      case ProcessingState.buffering:
        return AudioProcessingState.buffering;
      case ProcessingState.ready:
        return AudioProcessingState.ready;
      case ProcessingState.completed:
        return AudioProcessingState.completed;
      default:
        throw Exception("Invalid state: ${_player.processingState}");
    }
  }
}
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/ZCXAYH4K) is the full code for AudioService in-case needed.

Comment: When you print `tempList` at the end does it show what you expect? Any particular reason why `mediaItems` is global?

Comment: Well, when I try printing `tempList` in `playlist.dart` it comes out to be fine. But when I print it or anything else in `audioplayer.dart` then only their initialised values are printed. Earlier I was using a listener so I made it global but now there's no need for that as I'm no longer using that. So, no particular reason

Comment: Where are you actually calling `setValues`? I don't see it anywhere in that file, so tough to say whats going on. But if that hasn't fired before you access the list then it wouldn't be initialized. Generally, you might consider implementing a reactive state management solution and having that `mediaItems` list be observable.

Comment: I'm calling `setValues` on a different screen. On that screen, I have few list items and when user clicks on them then setValue with response as well as Navigator.push to the audioservice is called. I considered the case that the prcoess mighnot be completed by then and even tried calling `setValve` in `audioservice.dart` but still no success

Comment: Ok well I would step through the `setValues` function after calling it from the other page. In the debugger, confirm that A) The `response` that you're passing into it is properly initialized and B) `tempList` is fully initialized before `mediaItems = tempList;` I noticed that `queue = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments` is commented out so looks like you tried passing it to that screen. That should also work assuming you're getting a proper return value. This is definitely fixable but without see your full code I can't say for sure whats going on.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Sangwan5688/BlackHole-Private) is the full app code. The buggy things are in `trending.dart`, `playlist.dart` and `audioplayer.dart`. trending.dart show a list of some playlists on the home screen. So when a user clicks on any song of any list then 2 things happen. First the json response that I have for that particular list is passed to `playlist.dart` and second the screen changes to the one in `audioplayer.dart`.

Comment: Now in `playlist.dart` that json response is formatted in the format of `List <MediaItem>` as that's what audioplayer takes. It just adds the MediaItems to a list named `mediaItems` and that list is being accessed in `audioplayer.dart`. But it comes out to be an empty list even though `setValues` added elements to it. I tried different thing but still unsuccessful. You can change the code in `playlist.dart` as you like. What I want is just to pass a formatted List<MediaItem> from the response in `library.dart` to the queue in `audioplayer.dart`

Comment: I tried accessing other paramteres of `playlist.dart` and they also come out oe be the ones initalized. I guess something is wrong either with my implitation of class in `playlist.dart` or in `audioplayer.dart`. I even tried directly passing the json response in `trending.dart` to `audioplayer.dart` using `ModalRoute` but still no success. So, i assume something is wrong with `audioplayer.dart`

Comment: As I mentioned in your original question, I suspect you are not correctly communicating between isolates as outlined in the audio_service README. Your question could be made clearer by going over every instance where you set and access the playlist, indicating clearly "where" it is being accessed from (UI isolate or background isolate). If we have to go back-and-forth in the comments section, it means the question itself probably needs to be rewritten as a clearer question.

Comment: @RyanHeise Well till now even I wasn't clear what's happening and I'm new to Flutter and the package `audio_service`. Well, I tried discovering more and have made the necessary changes to the question above. When I try to access the queue inside `AudioPlayerTask` class then it comes out to be `empty`. I have made comments in the code to help. Now can you help? Do I have to do something to access the queue variable inside `AudioPlayerTask`? Sorry for all the inconvenience till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer update: Since v0.18, this sort of pitfall doesn't exist since the UI and background code run in a shared isolate. The answer below is only relevant for v0.17 and earlier.)

audio_service runs your `BackgroundAudioTask` in a separate isolate. In the README, it is put this way:

> Note that your UI and background task run in separate isolates and do not share memory. The only way they communicate is via message passing. Your Flutter UI will only use the `AudioService` API to communicate with the background task, while your background task will only use the `AudioServiceBackground` API to interact with the UI and other clients.

The key point there is that isolates do not share memory. If you set a "global" variable in the UI isolate, it will not be set in the background isolate because the background isolate has its own separate block of memory. That is why your global `queue` variable is null. It is not actually the same variable, because now you actually have two copies of the variable: one in the UI isolate which has been set with a value, and the other in the background isolate which has not (yet) been set with a value.

Now, your background isolate does "later" set its own copy of the queue variable to something, and this happens via the message passing API where you pass the queue from the UI isolate into `updateQueue` and the background isolate receive that message and stores it into its own copy of the variable in `onUpdateQueue`. If you were to print out the queue after this point it would no longer be null.

There is also a line in your `onStart` where you are attempting to set the queue, although you should probably delete that code and let the queue only be set in `onUpdateQueue`. You should not attempt to access the queue in `onStart` since your queue won't receive its value until `onUpdateQueue`. If you want to avoid any null pointer exception before its set, you can initialise the queue in the background isolate to an empty list, and it will eventually get replaced by a non-empty list in `onUpdateQueue` without ever being null.

I would also suggest you avoid making `queue` a global variable. Global variables are generally bad, but in this case, it may actually be confusing you into thinking that that queue variable is the same in both the UI and the background isolate when in reality each isolate will have its own copy of the variable perhaps with different values. Thus, your code will be clearer if you make two separate "local" variables. One inside the UI and one inside the background task.

One more suggestion is that you should note that the methods in the message passing API are asynchronous methods. You should wait for the audio service to start before you send messages to it, such as setting the queue. AND you should wait for the queue to be set before you try to play from the queue:

```dart
await AudioService.start(....);
// Now the service has started, it is safe to send messages.
await AudioService.updateQueue(...);
// Now the queue has been updated, it is safe to play from it.
```

Comment: Oh, I finally understand now. And the code is also working finally thanks a lot for help